# Writing to multiple files with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have some text files which have several columns. I'm using awk to only write the columns I want into an output file which I later analyze.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $2,FS,$3,FS,$4} input_files*.txt >> output_file.txt
```

Can I go one step farther and redirect the output of my awk command to more than one file depending on the value of let's say column $5? If column $5 = A, B, C and D I would end up with something like:

```
output_file_A.txt
output_file_B.txt
output_file_C.txt
output_file_D.txt
```

Thanks.

Carlos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $2,FS,$3,FS,$4 >> "output_file_"$5} input_files*.txt
```

The  redirection within `awk` works exactly like the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {fn="output_file_" $5 ".txt"} {print $2,FS,$3,FS,$4 > fn} input_files*.txt
```